why is my callback function reverting?? please i really need help
I have a challenge to solve, while the pair contract provided was having a swap function which is vuln to reentrance in my own understanding the swap was successful without trying the reentrance but the reentrance code keep reverting, here is the code for normal exploit,
// SPDX-License-Identifier: SEE LICENSE IN LICENSE
pragma solidity 0.8.19;

import {Test, console} from "forge-std/Test.sol";

interface ISwapRouter {
    function swapExactTokensForTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint[] memory amounts);
}

interface IPair {
    function swap(uint amount0Out, uint amount1Out, address to, bytes calldata data) external;
}

interface IERC20 {
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
}

contract CTFTest is Test {

    IERC20 private token0;
    IERC20 private token1;
    IPair private CTFPair;
    ISwapRouter private router;
    address public attacker;

    function setUp() public {
        vm.createSelectFork("testnet", 15306820);

        token0 = IERC20(0x4EEDdCc7C8714A684311F8b01154B5686A0f612f);
        token1 = IERC20(0x55d398326f99059fF775485246999027B3197955);
        router = ISwapRouter(0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E);
        CTFPair = IPair(0x46Cf1cF8c69595804ba91dFdd8d6b960c9B0a7C4);
        attacker = msg.sender;

        deal(address(token0), address(this), 1 ether);
    }

    function testExploit() public {
        emit log_named_decimal_uint("[Begin] token0 before exploit", token0.balanceOf(address(this)), 18);
        emit log_named_decimal_uint("[Begin] token1 before exploit", token1.balanceOf(address(this)), 18);

        require(msg.sender == attacker, "Only attacker can solve the CTF");

        require(token0.approve(address(router), token0.balanceOf(address(this))), "Approval failed");

        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = address(token0);
        path[1] = address(token1);

        uint256 amountIn = token0.balanceOf(address(this));
        uint256 amountOutMin = 0;
        router.swapExactTokensForTokens(amountIn, amountOutMin, path, address(this), block.timestamp);

        uint256 token0CTFBalance = token0.balanceOf(address(CTFPair));
        uint256 token1CTFBalance = token1.balanceOf(address(CTFPair));
        emit log_named_uint("token0 DEX balance before swap", token0CTFBalance);
        emit log_named_uint("token1 DEX balance before swap", token1CTFBalance);

        emit log_named_decimal_uint("[End] token0 after exploit", token0.balanceOf(address(this)), 18);
        emit log_named_decimal_uint("[End] token1 after exploit", token1.balanceOf(address(this)), 18);
    }
    receive() external payable {}
}"

Test result:
Ran 1 test for src/CTFswap.sol.sol:CTFTest
[PASS] testExploit() (gas: 132987)
Logs:
  [Begin] token0 before exploit: 1.000000000000000000
  [Begin] token1 before exploit: 0.000000000000000000
  token0 CTF balance before swap: 558803434103864515186885
  token1 CTF balance before swap: 505703528668073453818489
  [End] token0 after exploit: 0.000000000000000000
  [End] token1 after exploit: 0.902262387046718175

here is the vuln swap function in the pair contract which holds token0 and token1
function swap(uint256 amount0Out, uint256 amount1Out, address to, bytes calldata data) public {
    require(amount0Out > 0 || amount1Out > 0, "Pair: INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT");
    require(amount0Out < _getReserves && amount1Out < stor_7_14_27, "Pair: INSUFFICIENT_LIQUIDITY");

    if (amount0Out > 0) {
        privateTransfer(amount0Out, to, _token0);
    }
    if (amount1Out > 0) {
        privateTransfer(amount1Out, to, _token1);
    }
    if (data.length > 0) {
        (bool success, ) = to.call(data);
        require(success, "Pair: CALLBACK_FAILED");
    }

    uint256 balance0 = IERC20(_token0).balanceOf(address(this));
    uint256 balance1 = IERC20(_token1).balanceOf(address(this));
    require(balance0 >= _getReserves - amount0Out && balance1 >= stor_7_14_27 - amount1Out, "Pair: INSUFFICIENT_INPUT_AMOUNT");

    uint256 amount0In = balance0 > _getReserves ? balance0 - (_getReserves - amount0Out) : 0;
    uint256 amount1In = balance1 > stor_7_14_27 ? balance1 - (stor_7_14_27 - amount1Out) : 0;
    require(amount0In > 0 || amount1In > 0, "Pair: INSUFFICIENT_INPUT_AMOUNT");

    sync(balance0, balance1, amount0In, amount1In);
    emit Swap(msg.sender, amount0Out, amount1Out, amount0In, amount1In, to);
}

with this code to reenter the swap function before updating the "balances" of both tokens,
// SPDX-License-Identifier: SEE LICENSE IN LICENSE
pragma solidity 0.8.19;

import {Test, console} from "forge-std/Test.sol";

interface ISwapRouter {
    function swapExactTokensForTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint[] memory amounts);
}

interface IPair {
    function swap(uint amount0Out, uint amount1Out, address to, bytes calldata data) external;
}

interface IERC20 {
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
}

contract CTFTest is Test {

    IERC20 private token0;
    IERC20 private token1;
    IPair private CTFPair;
    ISwapRouter private router;
    address public attacker;

    function setUp() public {
        vm.createSelectFork("testnet", 15306820);

        token0 = IERC20(0x55d398326f99059fF775485246999027B3197955);
        token1 = IERC20(0x4EEDdCc7C8714A684311F8b01154B5686A0f612f);
        router = ISwapRouter(0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E);
        CTFPair = IPair(0x4EEDdCc7C8714A684311F8b01154B5686A0f612f);
        attacker = msg.sender;

        deal(address(token0), address(this), 1 ether);
    }

    function testExploit() public {
        emit log_named_decimal_uint("[Begin] token0 before exploit", token0.balanceOf(address(this)), 18);
        emit log_named_decimal_uint("[Begin] token1 before exploit", token1.balanceOf(address(this)), 18);

        require(msg.sender == attacker, "Only attacker can start the exploit");

        require(token0.approve(address(router), token0.balanceOf(address(this))), "Approval failed");

        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = address(token0);
        path[1] = address(token1);

        uint256 amountIn = token0.balanceOf(address(this));
        uint256 amountOutMin = 0; // Set to a low value to ensure the swap goes through
        router.swapExactTokensForTokens(amountIn, amountOutMin, path, address(this), block.timestamp);

        require(token1.approve(address(CTFPair), token1.balanceOf(address(this))), "Approval failed");

        uint256 token0CTFBalance = token0.balanceOf(address(CTFPair));
        uint256 token1CTFBalance = token1.balanceOf(address(CTFPair));
        emit log_named_uint("token0 CTF balance before swap", token0CTFBalance);
        emit log_named_uint("token1 CTF balance before swap", token1CTFBalance);

        // Swap token1 for token0, draining the pool
        CTFPair.swap(0, token1.balanceOf(address(this)), address(this), bytes(""));

        emit log_named_decimal_uint("[End]  token0 after exploit", token0.balanceOf(address(this)), 18);
        emit log_named_decimal_uint("[End]  token1 after exploit", token1.balanceOf(address(this)), 18);
    }
    receive() external payable {}
}

got his error from the trace.
[FAIL. Reason: revert: pair Swap: INSUFFICIENT_INPUT_AMOUNT] testExploit() (gas: 215046)
Logs:
  [Begin] Attacker token0 before exploit: 1.000000000000000000
  [Begin] Attacker token1 before exploit: 0.000000000000000000
  token0 CTF balance before swap: 558803434103864515186885
  token1 CTF balance before swap: 505703528668073453818489
Traces:
  [187546] CTFTest::testExploit()
    ├─ [2552] 0x191E94fa59739e188dcE837F7f6978d84727AD01::balanceOf(CTFTest: [0x7FA9385bE102ac3EAc297483Dd6233D62b3e1496]) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 1000000000000000000 [1e18]
    ├─ emit log_named_decimal_uint(key: "[Begin] Attacker token0 before exploit", val: 1000000000000000000 [1e18], decimals: 18)
    ├─ [2607] 0xb3A8F0f0da9ffC65318aA39E55079796093029AD::balanceOf(CTFTest: [0x7FA9385bE102ac3EAc297483Dd6233D62b3e1496]) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 0
    ├─ emit log_named_decimal_uint(key: "[Begin] Attacker token1 before exploit", val: 0, decimals: 18)
    ├─ [552] 0x191E94fa59739e188dcE837F7f6978d84727AD01::balanceOf(CTFTest: [0x7FA9385bE102ac3EAc297483Dd6233D62b3e1496]) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 1000000000000000000 [1e18]
    ├─ [24455] 0x191E94fa59739e188dcE837F7f6978d84727AD01::approve(0x4ddDD324F205e5989bAF8aD0FFCa41f4E5d9841D, 1000000000000000000 [1e18])
    │   ├─ emit Approval(owner: CTFTest: [0x7FA9385bE102ac3EAc297483Dd6233D62b3e1496], spender: 0x4ddDD324F205e5989bAF8aD0FFCa41f4E5d9841D, value: 1000000000000000000 [1e18])
    │   └─ ← true
    ├─ [552] 0x191E94fa59739e188dcE837F7f6978d84727AD01::balanceOf(CTFTest: [0x7FA9385bE102ac3EAc297483Dd6233D62b3e1496]) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 1000000000000000000 [1e18]
    ├─ [90437] 0x4ddDD324F205e5989bAF8aD0FFCa41f4E5d9841D::swapExactTokensForTokens(1000000000000000000 [1e18], 1, [0x191E94fa59739e188dcE837F7f6978d84727AD01, 0xb3A8F0f0da9ffC65318aA39E55079796093029AD], CTFTest: [0x7FA9385bE102ac3EAc297483Dd6233D62b3e1496], 1719221276 [1.719e9])
    │   ├─ [2526] 0x40320a9B3e8458cE3dd3E0Ad79fc5208F00510a3::getReserves() [staticcall]
    │   │   └─ ← 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007654bd9b6347d81550c5000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006b164ac93258f9a7ad58000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006679238a
    │   ├─ [12021] 0x191E94fa59739e188dcE837F7f6978d84727AD01::transferFrom(CTFTest: [0x7FA9385bE102ac3EAc297483Dd6233D62b3e1496], 0x40320a9B3e8458cE3dd3E0Ad79fc5208F00510a3, 1000000000000000000 [1e18])
    │   │   ├─ emit Transfer(from: CTFTest: [0x7FA9385bE102ac3EAc297483Dd6233D62b3e1496], to: 0x40320a9B3e8458cE3dd3E0Ad79fc5208F00510a3, value: 1000000000000000000 [1e18])
    │   │   └─ ← true
    │   ├─ [62811] 0x40320a9B3e8458cE3dd3E0Ad79fc5208F00510a3::swap(0, 902262387046718175 [9.022e17], CTFTest: [0x7FA9385bE102ac3EAc297483Dd6233D62b3e1496], 0x)
    │   │   ├─ [27768] 0xb3A8F0f0da9ffC65318aA39E55079796093029AD::transfer(CTFTest: [0x7FA9385bE102ac3EAc297483Dd6233D62b3e1496], 902262387046718175 [9.022e17])
    │   │   │   ├─ emit Transfer(from: 0x40320a9B3e8458cE3dd3E0Ad79fc5208F00510a3, to: GlydexTest: [0x7FA9385bE102ac3EAc297483Dd6233D62b3e1496], value: 902262387046718175 [9.022e17])
    │   │   │   └─ ← true
    │   │   ├─ [552] 0x191E94fa59739e188dcE837F7f6978d84727AD01::balanceOf(0x40320a9B3e8458cE3dd3E0Ad79fc5208F00510a3) [staticcall]
    │   │   │   └─ ← 558803434103864515186885 [5.588e23]
    │   │   ├─ [607] 0xb3A8F0f0da9ffC65318aA39E55079796093029AD::balanceOf(0x40320a9B3e8458cE3dd3E0Ad79fc5208F00510a3) [staticcall]
    │   │   │   └─ ← 505703528668073453818489 [5.057e23]
    │   │   ├─ emit Sync(: 558803434103864515186885 [5.588e23], : 505703528668073453818489 [5.057e23])
    │   │   ├─ emit Swap(param0: 0x4ddDD324F205e5989bAF8aD0FFCa41f4E5d9841D, param1: 1000000000000000000 [1e18], param2: 0, param3: 0, param4: 902262387046718175 [9.022e17], param5: CTFTest: [0x7FA9385bE102ac3EAc297483Dd6233D62b3e1496])
    │   │   └─ ← ()
    │   └─ ← [1000000000000000000 [1e18], 902262387046718175 [9.022e17]]
    ├─ [607] 0xb3A8F0f0da9ffC65318aA39E55079796093029AD::balanceOf(CTFTest: [0x7FA9385bE102ac3EAc297483Dd6233D62b3e1496]) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 902262387046718175 [9.022e17]
    ├─ [24648] 0xb3A8F0f0da9ffC65318aA39E55079796093029AD::approve(0x40320a9B3e8458cE3dd3E0Ad79fc5208F00510a3, 902262387046718175 [9.022e17])
    │   ├─ emit Approval(owner: CTFTest: [0x7FA9385bE102ac3EAc297483Dd6233D62b3e1496], spender: 0x40320a9B3e8458cE3dd3E0Ad79fc5208F00510a3, value: 902262387046718175 [9.022e17])
    │   └─ ← true
    ├─ [552] 0x191E94fa59739e188dcE837F7f6978d84727AD01::balanceOf(0x40320a9B3e8458cE3dd3E0Ad79fc5208F00510a3) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 558803434103864515186885 [5.588e23]
    ├─ [607] 0xb3A8F0f0da9ffC65318aA39E55079796093029AD::balanceOf(0x40320a9B3e8458cE3dd3E0Ad79fc5208F00510a3) [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← 505703528668073453818489 [5.057e23]
    ├─ emit log_named_uint(key: "token0 CTF balance before swap", val: 558803434103864515186885 [5.588e23])
    ├─ emit log_named_uint(key: "token1 CTF balance before swap", val: 505703528668073453818489 [5.057e23])
    ├─ [33150] 0x40320a9B3e8458cE3dd3E0Ad79fc5208F00510a3::swap(558803434103864515186884 [5.588e23], 0, DefaultSender: [0x1804c8AB1F12E6bbf3894d4083f33e07309d1f38], 0x)
    │   ├─ [25327] 0x191E94fa59739e188dcE837F7f6978d84727AD01::transfer(DefaultSender: [0x1804c8AB1F12E6bbf3894d4083f33e07309d1f38], 558803434103864515186884 [5.588e23])
    │   │   ├─ emit Transfer(from: 0x40320a9B3e8458cE3dd3E0Ad79fc5208F00510a3, to: DefaultSender: [0x1804c8AB1F12E6bbf3894d4083f33e07309d1f38], value: 558803434103864515186884 [5.588e23])
    │   │   └─ ← true
    │   ├─ [552] 0x191E94fa59739e188dcE837F7f6978d84727AD01::balanceOf(0x40320a9B3e8458cE3dd3E0Ad79fc5208F00510a3) [staticcall]
    │   │   └─ ← 1
    │   ├─ [607] 0xb3A8F0f0da9ffC65318aA39E55079796093029AD::balanceOf(0x40320a9B3e8458cE3dd3E0Ad79fc5208F00510a3) [staticcall]
    │   │   └─ ← 505703528668073453818489 [5.057e23]
    │   └─ ← revert: Pair: INSUFFICIENT_INPUT_AMOUNT
    └─ ← revert: Pair Swap: INSUFFICIENT_INPUT_AMOUNT

thank you for the insight.

I think you should update your question to make it easier for reading. Do not just copy all stuff and paste it here. Like the test result, put it in code area at least, and with the traces, you can take a screenshot and up it instead of copy
